# Call the same function on a list and return a list with no duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this function:

```
medIntCategory = MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text(category.category.text)
```

However now I have a list of categories called categories.

I would like to execute the above code for each category and get back a list of medIntCategories, but with no duplicates.

Is there a simple way to do this since I am only dealing with integers?

in simple terms:

```
categoryList = []
for each category in categories do
categoryList += MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text(category.category.text)
end
```

But with duplicate checking

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I am only dealing with integers"? Are you saying that `MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text` returns an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
category_list = categories.map{|category|
  MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text(category.category.text)
}.uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @result=Array.new
   ##assuming that it returns an array
    medIntCategory = MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text(category.category.text)
    ##get the first category obtained
    @result << medIntCategory 
    if medIntCategory.present?
      medIntCategory.each do |m|
         ##add in same array only if not present
         if !@result.include?(m)
             @result << m.find_by_category_text(c.category.text)
         end
      end
    ##return a unique value array
    @result.flatten.compact.uniq unless @result.blank?
    end
```

**HOPE IT HELPS**

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
    category_list = []
    categories.each do |category|
      category_list << MedicalInterventionCategory.find_by_category_text(category.category.text).distinct
    end
```

Comment: How does this handle dupes?